# 400 error while accessing ExchangeService through Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am facing a wired problem and not able to figure out the solution. Any suggestions/solutions on this will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.
**Context**: The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
C# App is throwing an error with the above message while instance/object of the ExchangeService is Calling GetRoomLists method.

**Details**: The aim is to get the list of Rooms associated with specific user belongs to a corporate Exchange Server. To achieve the purpose, following code snippets are written

```
    var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                        .Create("*******")
                        .WithClientSecret("*******")
                        .WithTenantId("******")
                        .Build();

   
 

    var ewsScopes2 = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
             
    var authResult2 = cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes2).ExecuteAsync().Result;


// Configure the ExchangeService with the access token

    var _service = new ExchangeService();
                        _service.Url = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events");

                   
                

_service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult2.AccessToken);
               

 _service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "abc@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com");
            }
                   
    EmailAddressCollection roomList = _service.GetRoomLists();
```

While trying to access the GetRoomLists, we are getting the error “The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.”

**AAD** **Configuration**:
In Azure AD the Graph object has delegated permission to Calendars.Room resource.

Comment: Ïs ExchangeService your class?

Comment: No it comes under the namespace Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.

Comment: You should tag the programming language you are using, and you should provide a self-contained reproducible test case.

Comment: I tagged with Microsoft Graph which may help to reduce the scope and also the code snippet is provided and by getting the glimpse of the syntax, identifying the language as C# will work. anyway, I will keep that in my mind.

Comment: In addition to that for adding self contained reproducible test case as a must. Why we need that. If it is mandatory then it should be  part of validation process for each and every post in stack overflow. Making the thing simple is really complex it seems and that too when the world is full of technical jargons. I got the solution and required advise from a member having required experience and acumen on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // Configure the ExchangeService with the access token
 var _service = new ExchangeService();
                    _service.Url = new 
Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events");            
_service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult2.AccessToken);
_service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "abc@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com");
        }
EmailAddressCollection roomList = _service.GetRoomLists();
```

This is all Exchange Web Services (EWS which is a SOAP based API) code so won't work against the Graph (which is REST based). The equivalent would be to use the Graph SDK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview and the use the Places Endpoint. To use this endpoint you will need to the Place.Read.All Application permission.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/place-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Note you might need to be aware of this issue with the v5 version of the SDK https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/21503 as that will affect what your tying to do.

Comment: Thanks Glen for the suggestions and advise. I will work on that.